# Table with addresses or registers, assembler x86

Tags: assembly, x86, intel-syntax

I have to write destinations and values of registers after operations.

Fields written in italics are written by me.  Fields written in bold (like the instructions) were written by my professor.

I had tried to fill all fields but not really sure about answer.
 I would be glad if you would tell me what is wrong, thanks! :)

[image: table with assembly answears]

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you need. Show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`push eax` stores a register to memory](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html).  **`push` has two outputs**: `ESP-=4` (the register), and then `[ESP]=eax` (the memory address).  I guess you can fit both outputs into one row in your table.

That's why the sequence included an LEA to set ESP earlier: normal code wouldn't do that, but this assignment needs the numeric value of ESP to be known.

---

Your 2nd mistake is in `sub edx,ebx`.  EDX was zeroed by the previous instruction, but EBX is still 0x200.  `sub` does unsigned / 2's complement binary subtraction which wraps around, not saturating to zero.  Try it in a debugger, or in C with `uint32_t`.